# celery task received but not executed (eventlet, django)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, eventlet

I faced a problem that when running celery with `eventlet` and remote database (Redis) tasks come but are not executed, before that I used `gevent` and it worked correctly with both local and remote databases, but it does not have the ability to stop tasks, I tried all the options I found on the Internet and on StackOverflow, but none of them helped. I add my settings there

Django settings:

```
# settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = REDIS_CONN_URL + "0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = REDIS_CONN_URL + "0"
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 1000
```

Celery settings:

```
import os
import ssl

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "SailAPI.settings")

celery_app = Celery(
    "SailAPI",
    broker_use_ssl={"ssl_cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, "ssl_ca_certs": ssl.get_default_verify_paths().cafile},
    redis_backend_use_ssl={"ssl_cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, "ssl_ca_certs": ssl.get_default_verify_paths().cafile},
)

celery_app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

celery_app.conf.update(
    enable_utc=True,
    timezone="UTC",
    worker_concurrency=8,
    worker_pool="eventlet",
)

celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "update_user_status": {
        "task": "user_app.tasks.update_user_status",
        "schedule": crontab(hour="4", minute="0", day_of_week="sat"),
    }
}

celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

The problem is that tasks that are added to the queue are not executed. I use an `eventlet` (because it has the ability to stop tasks that are running) and when I run it locally (Windows) with a local database (redis) it works fine, accepts tasks, executes them, stops at the command, but when I threw the code on the server (Linux) and ran celery there with this command `celery -A SailAPI.celery worker -l info -P eventlet -E` I got the following logs

```
 
 -------------- celery@sail-backend v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-78-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2023-10-03 20:55:33
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         SailAPI:0x7f7f5dcf8d50
- ** ---------- .> transport:   rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . chat_gpt.tasks.send_message_to_gpt_task
  . payment_system.tasks.create_payment_url
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_failed
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_success
  . user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription
  . user_app.tasks.update_user_status

[2023-10-03 20:55:33,395: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0: Error while reading from <dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>: ('timed out',).
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2023-10-03 20:55:35,416: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0: Error while reading from <dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>: ('timed out',).
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)

[2023-10-03 20:55:39,437: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0: Error while reading from <dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>: ('timed out',).
Trying again in 6.00 seconds... (3/100)
```

But if I run this on my local machine I got:

```
 -------------- celery@DESKTOP-4FC47C2 v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)          
--- ***** -----                                                       
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0 2023-10-03 21:01:24         
- *** --- * ---                                                       
- ** ---------- [config]                                              
- ** ---------- .> app:         SailAPI:0x22273aa5950                 
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:16379/0             
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:16379/0             
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1000 (eventlet)                       
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON                                    
--- ***** -----                                                       
 -------------- [queues]                                              
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                                                                      
                                                                      
[tasks]                                                               
  . chat_gpt.tasks.send_message_to_gpt_task                           
  . payment_system.tasks.create_payment_url                           
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_failed                        
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_success                       
  . user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription                            
  . user_app.tasks.update_user_status                                 

[2023-10-03 21:01:28,206: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:16379/0

[2023-10-03 21:01:28,220: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-10-03 21:01:29,259: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-10-03 21:01:29,275: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-4FC47C2 ready.

[2023-10-03 21:01:29,284: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to redis://localhost:16379/0.
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,854: INFO/MainProcess] Task user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription[1f39ac32-638a-4903-b489-7e2d87e26afb] received
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,858: WARNING/MainProcess] Checking user subscription...
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,879: DEBUG/MainProcess] (0.000) SELECT "user_profiles"."id", "user_profiles"."system_user_id", "user_profiles"."user_email", "user_profiles"."user_username", "user_profiles"."user_first_name", "user_profiles"."user_la
st_name", "user_profiles"."user_avatar", "user_profiles"."status", "user_profiles"."subscription", "user_profiles"."subscription_type", "user_profiles"."subscription_start_day", "user_profiles"."subscription_end_day", "user_profiles"."sub
scription_id", "user_profiles"."user_language", "user_profiles"."user_interests", "user_profiles"."assistance_interest_user", "user_profiles"."referral_utm_code", "user_profiles"."requests_per_day" FROM "user_profiles" WHERE "user_profile
s"."system_user_id" = 2 LIMIT 21; args=(2,); alias=default
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,880: WARNING/MainProcess] User subscription status: False
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,880: WARNING/MainProcess] User subscription id: None
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,880: WARNING/MainProcess] User subscription checked.
[2023-10-03 21:01:56,912: INFO/MainProcess] Task user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription[1f39ac32-638a-4903-b489-7e2d87e26afb] succeeded in 0.0470000000204891s: None
```

If on dedicate server I try run this command, I will receive tasks, but they will not be completed

```
celery -A SailAPI.celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=100 --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair
```

Celery Debug info:

```
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,424: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,425: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,425: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {StateDB, Beat, Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, Consumer}
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,754: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,754: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,762: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Agent, Heart, Gossip, event loop}
 
 -------------- celery@sail-backend v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-78-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2023-10-03 20:27:11
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         SailAPI:0x7f89c422d710
- ** ---------- .> transport:   rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 100 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . chat_gpt.tasks.send_message_to_gpt_task
  . payment_system.tasks.create_payment_url
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_failed
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_success
  . user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription
  . user_app.tasks.update_user_status

[2023-10-03 20:27:11,839: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,839: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,839: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,839: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,839: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,839: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,866: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,866: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,866: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,869: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,870: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,870: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,870: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,870: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,870: INFO/MainProcess] celery@sail-backend ready.
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,870: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->100
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,872: INFO/MainProcess] Task user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription[e4baa163-f3bf-4a85-a3f1-c5829e8ad90b] received
[2023-10-03 20:27:11,872: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function fast_trace_task at 0x7f89c418af20> (args:('user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription', 'e4baa163-f3bf-4a85-a3f1-c5829e8ad90b', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription', 'id': 'e4baa163-f3bf-4a85-a3f1-c5829e8ad90b', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': 'e4baa163-f3bf-4a85-a3f1-c5829e8ad90b', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': '(2,)', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen42524@DESKTOP-4FC47C2', 'ignore_result': False, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}, 'redelivered': True, 'properties': {'correlation_id': 'e4baa163-f3bf-4a85-a3f1-c5829e8ad90b', 'reply_to': '90f45e4e-4760-3bb1-b8ed-6b7f5be3d767', 'delivery_mode': 2, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery', 'redelivered': True}, 'priority': 0, 'body_encoding': 'base64', 'delivery_tag': 'e8b47759-3ee2-4177-a221-cb16093cad15'}, 'reply_to': '90f45e4e-4760-3bb1-b8ed-6b7f5be3d767', 'correlation_id': 'e4baa163-f3bf-4a85-a3f1-c5829e8ad90b', 'hostname': 'celery@sail-backend',... kwargs:{})
```

If I try run celery like this:

```
celery -A SailAPI.celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG --pool=eventlet --concurrency=100 --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair
```

```
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,506: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,507: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,508: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Beat, StateDB, Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, Consumer}
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,512: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,512: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,518: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Heart, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, Agent, event loop}
 
 -------------- celery@sail-backend v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-78-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2023-10-03 21:15:47
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         SailAPI:0x7efd332d34d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 100 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . chat_gpt.tasks.send_message_to_gpt_task
  . payment_system.tasks.create_payment_url
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_failed
  . payment_system.tasks.handle_payment_success
  . user_app.tasks.check_user_subscription
  . user_app.tasks.update_user_status

[2023-10-03 21:15:47,538: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,538: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,538: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,538: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2023-10-03 21:15:47,566: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to rediss://:<dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>/0: Error while reading from <dedicate_database>:<dedicate_port>: ('timed out',).
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

I every time will be recive that cannot connect to dedicate database, I dont know why, because if I run this for local database server(redis) everything good